# Rails delete has_many through association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, associations, sql-delete, has-many-through

I have has_many through association with User, Attachment and Form model, I want to delete associaton only, not the attachment. I wrote delete method named "sil"

> user.rb

```
  has_many :forms
  has_many :attachments, through: :forms
```

> attachment.rb

```
has_many :forms
has_many :users, through: :forms
```

> form.rb

```
 belongs_to :user
 belongs_to :attachment
```

> sil method

```
def sil # remove the product from user
 @user = User.find(params[:id])
 attachment = Attachment.find(params[:attachid])
 @user.attachments.delete(attachment)
 redirect_to user_path(@user.id)
end
```

> view

```
<%= button_to "Sil",attach ,method: "delete",:controller => "attachments", :action => "sil" , :attachid =>attach.id %>
```

I have resources routes for attachments and I have destroy method for attachments to delete an element. I need help for view and route for sil method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
resources :attachments do
  member do
    delete 'sil'
  end
end
```

routing helper like this:

```
sil_attachment_path(id: attachmentid, user_id: userid)
```

Comment: I use delete 'sil' instead of get , do I have to give params in path like u did ?

Comment: you are finding both user and attachment in your action then get to the record you need to pass the params with your link same as I did.